# Number to letters

Tags: code-golf, string, number, alphabet

#### Your task

Given a numerical string or integer \$\ge 0\$ (which may have leading zeros), convert it to letters using the below rules.

#### Rules

Loop through the digits:

- If the digit is `0` or `1`, combine it with the next digit and output that letter of the alphabet (0-indexed).
- If the digit is `2`, combine with the next digit ONLY IF the next digit is between `0` and `5` (inclusive). Otherwise, output `c` (2nd letter of the alphabet, 0-indexed).
- If the digit is `3` or more, output that letter of the alphabet (0-indexed).

#### Example

Our input is the number `12321`.

We loop through the digits:

- `1`: this is less than 2, so we keep this and wait for the next digit.
- `2`: combine with the previous digit, `1`, to get `12`. Index into the lowercase alphabet (0-indexed) to get `m`
- `3`: this is more than 2, so we output the 3rd letter of the alphabet (0-indexed), `d`
- `2`: this is 2, so we check the next digit. It is less than 6, so we wait.
- `1`: combine with the previous digit, `2`, to get `21`. Index into the lowercase alphabet (0-indexed) to get `v`

Our output is `mdv`.

#### Test cases

##### Random

```
Input   Output
132918  ncjs
79411   hjel
695132  gjfnc
800125  iamf
530987  fdjih
144848  oeiei
93185   jdsf
922846  jwieg
187076  shhg
647325  gehdz
```

##### Edge-cases

```
Input  Output
0      a
1      b
25     z
26     cg
000    aa
123    md
0123   bx
1230   mda
12310  mdk
12345  mdef
00012  abc
```

Feel free to create your own test cases in [this TIO](https://tio.run/##nZLRbsIwDEXf/RV@o1G1icIYG2q@BE2IgQeWQlqlrmBf34Uk64o2Hro@NbbvzT1W6k85VnbedXyqKyfYiGN7ALDt6Z0camRbt5IpYLuniz9PoWrFl/zvZAJwPrIhjM0SDdksKhU@YLEC9N@eDyzBSVJzHebfVGjzR5oocRYFoRocc41FXzIkEiL5jFmQKMzxxrGfTRlznYAet82OeWOqM7ndtqH1NUw0VFFFpg@i9TCJpYts7jHkRaJIJIPhUuPix@UO01iu/7FFvoZW431inu8VDS1Gywf44Ff1x5u5fS@/NzDqSqjd9Rg1quuK2fxp8bx8eZ1@AQ) of some ungolfed Python code.

#### Clarifications

- Everything must be 0-indexed
- You cannot ignore leading 0s (see the 5th and 6th edge-cases)
- If the last digit is 0, 1, or 2, and it has not already been used by the previous digit, output "a", "b", or "c" respectively (see edge-cases)
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25328/114446)

Comment: It's worth updating the spec to directly indicate that a trailing ```0```, ```1``` or ```2``` with nothing following it should output ```a```, ```b``` or ```c``` (following the rule for ```3``` or more).  Clear (I think) from the 'edge cases', but better to spell it out.

Comment: @DominicvanEssen thanks. I've updated the challenge.

Comment: The following challenge should be: given any strings that contain only lower asciis, output the corresponding string with fewest numbers.

Comment: Many languanges (including node even though there's a node answer below) discard leading zeroes when reading integers. Those languages would need to read strings instead.

Comment: @Sandra I assumed it was allowed by default, but having the input surrounded by quotes (or doing anything similar to make sure leading zeros are not dropped) is fine.

Comment: Another suggested edge case: `000 -> aa`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen thanks, I've added that (as well as the other test case from your 05AB1E answer) in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), <s>17</s> 16.5 bytes (33 nibbles)

```
``;$$$:+`r<;?\`<`:"26"$$@"a"_>$@
```

```
``;                                 # launch recursive function:
   $                                # starting with input list of digits,
    $                               # stopping when argument is empty
     $                              #   and then returning the empty argument,
                                    # otherwise:
                `:"26"$             #   make a list of "26" and the argument string,
              `<                    #   sort this list of strings,
             \                      #   reverse it,
            ?          $            #   get the index of the argument in this,
           ;                        #   and save this as the number of elements
                                    #   to take from the argument (1 or 2);
          <                         #   now, take that many elements
        `r                          #   read this as an integer,
       +                "a"         #   add this to "a",
      :                             #   and append onto this
                           _        #   a recursive call with argument:
                            >$      #     drop the saved number of elements
                              @     #     from the current argument
```

[image]
[See some more test & edge cases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgZse.png)

Answer (score 9):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 49 bytes

```javascript
//                           we match all patterns consisting of either:
//              +----------> a '2' followed by '0' to '5', or
//              |      +---> any digit optionally preceded by '0' or '1'
//             _|__   _|__
//            /    \ /    \
s=>s.replace(/2[0-5]|[01]?./g,n=>Buffer([+n+97]))
//                               \_____________/
//                                      |
// and replace each of them with a <----+
// letter in lower case
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDdboMgAIXv9xTGK01XBUSBC7tkr2G8cAgKUWxkf1n27q6L2jZQbr@Pcw7o5rOxfFbn96OZWrHIcrHlySazOA8NF1GKKnDM698KwPolSbtnU55eP6QUc1QdzIGROo4XPhk7DSIZpi6SUQgzxCAN4zhI08BwbZ8cgTAMYRisQq/F4AoFyy8hW0KnpeGuQQGAKN8M1YzSFfIMMEo2QbZa9a4BMaZ4nzkJJZRrsAzSfN@pW@uVMIQoLrYI/aVE55VQAshu2L73hAKT7PqQTvTtj2uAMPg/q9F4Bff0zaWX5Bv1klFxR7m/HWXhFY@tt2vlW/P3g9sgvN1uHnB8/dyxFXL5Aw)

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 58 bytes

```python
f=lambda s:s and chr(97+int(s[:(I:=1+(s<"26"))]))+f(s[I:])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYtNDoIwFIT37xQNm/YFFlAEtZEDsPIAwqL8BRBr05Yop68QF/NlMvlGb258q/SijfdDschX00lihSVSdaQdDbuew0k5Zh@ClaJIQmZvAc8DxBoxHPa9FDV6bQ6JlkqvrnLkvrq9UITPOC09SQQQZzYxF9MhMATSf9teO9GYXj6B/O9zRCtHo4HNiD6GBHgGPIeEpxAf2BMfOGU/)

This is based on the observation that we can simply compare the entire leftover string to "26" to decide whether to consume one or two characters.

Answer (score 5):

## [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 83 bytes

```
>i:0(?;'0'-:2(?v:2=?v'a'+o
^ o+'a'+-'0'i*a<
+'a'~$o'c'v?(6:-'0'i<.01o
1o+'a'+*a$<.0
```

[Link](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiPmk6MCg/OycwJy06Mig/djoyPT92J2EnK29cbl4gbysnYScrLScwJ2kqYTxcbisnYSd+JG8nYyd2Pyg2Oi0nMCdpPC4wMW9cbjFvKydhJysqYSQ8LjAiLCJpbnB1dCI6IjI2MTMyOTE4MjE3Iiwic3RhY2siOiIiLCJtb2RlIjoibnVtYmVycyJ9)

[image]

Top row is basic reading lines and exiting at the end. Red part at the end is the single digit case.

Middle row is the 0 or 1 case.

Bottom row 2 rows are the 2 case. Top branch is C, bottom is 2 digit number.

Answer (score 5):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 32 bytes

```
2[0-5]|[01]?.
$*#a
+T`##l`_l`#\w
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DccxDsIwDAXQ/V8jTEUg27Fje@ISbG1FOjAgVQwIiYW7B972Xvf347mNITOdbP3OxOvljMNUNhyvvZS93/Zels8YXCU54KnMaGn/I4hYDFYpw8GqoYGsHIYUCW3gcPKGpl7Ffg) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
2[0-5]|[01]?.
```

Use @Arnauld's regex to identify the numbers from `0` to `25` inclusive.

```
$*#a
```

Replace each number with a string of that many `#`s followed by an `a`.

```
+T`##l`_l`#\w
```

Repeatedly cycle letters though the alphabet, decreasing the number of preceding `#`s each time, until there are no `#`s left.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 17 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
.œʒ€g3‹y₂‹«P}θAsè
```

Output as a list of characters.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f7@jkU5MeNa1JN37UsLPyUVMTkDq0OqD23A7H4sMr/v83MDAwNAIA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##HYs7CsJAFEW3EqZ@yPvM500VbK3sxUJBxMoiIKQQJIULiJsQdAHaKjYWLmI2Mk7SnPvh3n2zWu82@dDWpkrnvjJ1myefy7dP3X0r6fRsU9cVed3mx99j2ryveQZ5QcKRFEK0ROCjKxkUkdiBE4wagKxVqxCF1EFkVuuBNGDw4G2QMkQgKMKlZwFTzmIGiwNopHWlRzQjic3yDw).

**Explanation:**

```python
.œ                # Get all possible partitions of the (implicit) input
  ʒ         }     # Filter this list by:
   €       P      #  All parts in a partition
    g             #  Should have a length
     3‹           #  Less than 3
       y  «       #  And in addition should also all be
        ₂‹        #  Less than 26
            }θ    # After the filter: leave the last valid partition
              Asè # Index each inner index into the lowercase alphabet
                  # (after which this character-list is output implicitly as result)
```

Comment: So close: you got beaten by half a byte by the Nibbles answer.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 49 bytes

```ruby
->s{eval ['""',*s.scan(/2[0-5]|[01]?./)]*"<<97+"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1664OrUsMUchWl1JSV1Hq1ivODkxT0PfKNpA1zS2JtrAMNZeT18zVkvJxsbSXFup9n@BQlq0kqGRsZGhUux/AA)

Comment: Clever! Nice work.

Answer (score 3):

## Excel (ms365), 169 bytes

```
=DROP(REDUCE(VSTACK(A1,""),SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),LAMBDA(a,b,IFERROR(LET(x,LEFT(TAKE(a,1),2),y,IF(--x>25,LEFT(x),x),CHOOSE({1,2},RIGHT(a,LEN(a)-LEN(y)),a&CHAR(y+97))),a))),1)
```

The idea here is to use `REDUCE()` to iterate n-times (length of input) over this input and while doing so keep a shadow-record in the element next to given input with the alphabetic output while we check all numbers in order from left to right.

I do have a feeling this could be shortened though.

[image]

Comment: Having a bit of trouble reproducing your output in MS365 Excel V.2210 - output of B1 is equivalent to `={"","nnnnnn"}`

Comment: Do you happen to have a different locale language setting? It may affect the way an array is written in CHOOSE...otherwise I wouldn't know as it works for me. @TaylorAlexRaine

Comment: I tried a couple of different language settings including South Africa, US, and UK, and had no luck getting it to work - I don't doubt that your solution is working, but I suggest that you indicate version and language as Excel can be extremely picky about these settings

Comment: I'm going to have a look into that sometime soon when behind a pc 

Comment: @TaylorAlexRaine, right so I could reproduce your issue. As mentioned before you must be aware that arrays are written differently in different locale settings. The culprit is `=CHOOSE({1,2}` which in your locale settings may probably be written as `=CHOOSE({1\2}`.

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>42</s> 38 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to @coltim

Uses [loopy walt's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/254737/74062) recursive approach. There is probably some clever way to rewrite it using a fold.

It takes the length 2 prefix and compare it with 26 to decide if we convert 1 or 2 characters. After the conversion, it appends a recursive call on the remaining string.

```
{$[x;(`c$97+.n$x),o(n:1+26>.2$x)_x;x]}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxN0N1ugyAYBuBzrsIQD2xqGv4UaJNm97EsGyqobLUHHpR02a59IEjGGQ/v9xPM+bt8dZfqoy8lP56W0h3qe7Wc8ZG01xPx13d3cW8/AFQ1VPBQ/BbmpYYIFtsJ2mXF//QZFZImIoD9CKO0uygVBaHYD8DbEAUTmqRzKZMoZFQOoZ0+M+FggbTJxprNVNfngZhAAJferv5lS1EisfA2Wf2VjEuGsafRmiVVtrLxSW+zupkUE6Fb480Mdp5irqFICu7trmc9p0UYEyyMsMO610qKRSi1j1mn/5GECNZ6W6dp3LcTHPFgo56GZ1qFcRrG/gEItWYU)

Comment: You can trim one byte by using `$[x;...]` instead of `$[#x;...]` (empty lists are false-y, non-empty lists are truthy), and another byte by using `2$x` in place of `x@!2`

Comment: Similarly, `n$x` instead of `n#p` can save a pair of bytes (I would have edited the above, but I was too slow. oops)

Comment: thanks! i had completely forgotten the `n$string` overload

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 20 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ŒṖẈṀ’ỊƲƇV<26Ạ$ƇṪ‘ịØa
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUAAv/9qZWxsef//xZLhuZbhuojhuYDigJnhu4rGssaHVjwyNuG6oCTGh@G5quKAmOG7i8OYYf///ycwMzAxMDIyMjIn)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##FYo9CsJAEIX7OUUKS4ud/Z0F9RiCpYVNyAXsFpuIdhYSQcFarIJNkjKYe8xeZF2L9z2@xyt3VbVP6Xvh7sr9kbsQw42H09RO9XohLffP2VRz94qh4eE8NtvEw2c@1mUM92K5KmJ4TG08vDcpoZIeCZzXiGC9yQ4kBEoDRglPDlBr0gReIRnwUpK2gOSEs2C1U/koACGXzLtUIP7IEX9o8wM).

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 24 bytes

```
Ｗθ«≔⊕‹θ26ι§β✂θ⁰ι≔✂θιＬθ¹θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/788IzMnVUGjUFOhmovTsbg4Mz1PwzMvuSg1NzWvJDVFwye1uFijUEdBychMSVNTRyFT05qLM6AoM69Ew7HEMy8ltUIjSUchOCczORWkzACkQhOkBmoWXCZTR8EnNS@9JANol46CIRAXApXV/v9vaGRsYvpftywHAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Port of @loopywalt's Python solution.

```
Ｗθ«
```

Loop until the input is empty.

```
≔⊕‹θ26ι
```

Determine how many digits to extract.

```
§β✂θ⁰ι
```

Output the appropriate letter.

```
≔✂θιＬθ¹θ
```

Slice off those digits.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>85</s> 75 bytes

- -7 thanks to jdt
- -3 thanks to ceilingcat

Takes strings to preserve leading zeroes.

```c
f(*o,*s,u){for(;u=*s++;)*o++=97+((u-=48)>2|u==2&*s>53|!*s?u:u*10+*s++-48);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVBNcoMgFN7nFK/OtEXQGUCMWIb0ArlBmoW1Y6qTxkwMdmG8ei1CkpYFfO/7eQ8o43JfHHZTfTjDV1EfUN/WHyEMCwBL4Xqz1cM6YAnPmQwiWAdZLhhzaJmnlndQUsp46mCa0FxmDjIhpPCpPGHS6znnUiy9LjOaebgUWTI3sGP/1jqg3uf2a3/uA5ReNZ74@gbseVfYHYn0lmLzjekYAcaNWth5VXtCja4V2BoaQvzjAY4n@wEVCh73HegVvD3bHG5C5cT5u95NtZF0CxqG0bMVstw/l20NaLb2mirn77cKejvj@s6jOZefxQl56ZqyZIcCO8/V42KcKoTbCHeRCYf5tspo3BGiQtwSovOMIGRiLWS44hejNX/C3SpNLg@4ezUvBjNKZntsDWqcpp@y2he7boq/fwE)

Answer (score 2):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 64++ bytes

- Inspired by [ErikF's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/254773/112488).

```c
u;f(*o,*s){for(;u=*s++;)*o++=*s<54<u-49|!*s?49+u:u*10-431+*s++;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZFdb4IwGIXv@yveYYyUj62FysdQd7VsF2ZXS7ZEuWAIWoJgrMxkzr8@Vj7Um/bhnNMT@jY24zwq1nVdBamqlYYm8Ckt92pQTTWh6wHWSl2XOBmzSWUy//dOE0/M16vHSqPEZDbV29y5HvAizqtVAhNxWPHyfjNDN@kYb6J9I6HBKkl5kcD8@e3l/VX9xKAK/pOUKTT8ALePBQkxQrw4oG3EC/W75CuMTghASvBVpQuPhAZkBmh8EcIUGgtgrlDb8qmnGBJdn1HakuOPpd6iRwi1xi2ObeJ7bouUMY/JU32Jb1Ovy/iW5TGny3gucTt0mGv3JaTz2rWXLOdaREjvW3aXvoDcrw69Eus7m39UZMU5QHJtXiSTVyQBZDC5zI7jAHQ9w/3Nj9tkK5KDKkcjK0ZLMjIuSSlhHLSptPP5Igt7ZbeXA01VZWg6uYDpDEbDXIyWhdKljGbWbfSMzvVfnObRWtTmR1GafLvLecwP/w)

If the output not being null-terminated is a problem, it's 1 extra byte to write to `stdout`:

```c
u;f(*s){for(;u=*s++;)putchar(*s<54<u-49|!*s?49+u:u*10-431+*s++);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZHLboMwEEX3/oopURUMobXBvApJV1W7iLqq1EpRFohHYkQgiqGLpvx6qXkk7WZ8Zu74yjOOjbiIyl3XNUGmagKfs@qkBs1SE7oe4GNTx/voJIXQZmFjMP/7RhOPzNebh0ajxGAW1ftWHLTdjJdx0SQphKJOeHW3XyE0S9KMlymsn16f317UDwyq4F9plUHP9/CXbMgWI8TLGh0iXqqfFU8wOiMAWYJ8ARrfbGEJfQVgrVDL9KmnLCS6PqN0IMe3ZX1AjxBq2gPaFvE9d0DKmMfkrcnEt6g39vim6TFn7PFc4o7oMNeaTMioDXEqmc7ViJBJN62x@wLyvCr0Smzy7N@oSIs2QDL2m8/liCSAHMLLyjgOQNdzPE1@PMl9ZKpyaziFgOUK5tKKb/ItDgY9U/8l8vuEqsyVIW1R2/3EWRHtRGe8l5XBD8eCx7z@BQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [sclin](https://github.com/molarmanful/sclin), 32 bytes

```
"2[0-5]|[01]?."\; /#
"&":97+ c>S
```

[Try it here!](https://replit.com/@molarmanful/try-sclin) Port of @Arnauld's answer.

For testing purposes:

```
["132918""79411""695132""800125""530987""144848""93185""922846""187076""647325""0""1""25""26""123""0123""1230""12310""12345"] \>S map ; n>< n>o
"2[0-5]|[01]?."\; /#
"&":97+ c>S
```

Answer (score 1):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) -Rr, 43 bytes

```
[scan("2[0-5]|[01]?.")|tonumber+97]|implode
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYo7DoMwEET7PQZVooho117bu1XukBZR5ENBFDAB0vnscQzFvNFo3uuTc7M8buOhMg3Wrk0NUns5V8e0xvE73Lv5pKFN/TC947PLmaxREgjKRODVlQ2CSMaBs6gSgJiFBdSSOFBjhD2QBAwePAdbREAgKG3KYSzghhLcQDu5SHv5IIq/OK19HJdcX@c/)

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>54</s>  50 bytes

```
ic%:a)?v}
<v+*a  ~!
^>"a"+o>:2(}:2=}$:@6({*{+l2)*?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/PzNZ1SpR076slsumTFsrUUGhTpErzk4pUUk7387KSKPWysi2VsXKwUyjWqtaO8dIU8v@/39DYyNLQwsA)

**Explanation**

`ic%:a)?v}`
Get all the input, mod each by **12** to get numbers and reorder it in the input order.

```
v
~
>
```

Then discard the end-of-input-byte.

If we call the top of the stack **x** and the 2nd top value of the stack **y** then:

`:2(}:2=}$:@6({*{+l2)*?`
**If (x < 2 or (x == 2 and y < 6)) and len(stack) > 1**

`<v+*a  ~!`
**Then x = x * 10 + y**

`"a"+o`
Print **x + 97** as a character.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>73</s> 71 bytes

```python
lambda s:re.sub('2[0-5]|[01]?.',lambda c:chr(97+int(c[0])),s)
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYvLDoIwFET39yu6axuRtCgamxDXrvwAYAFYQpFHUy5REv8daXQxJ5OcGbtgMw6HtU6ytSv68lGQSTkdTnPJaJSKfZx/UiHza0iDv69U1Th2Oe/MgKxKRc55MHEwvR0dEqdX67yht8HOmCG5z7gVyuHVmE4TqYCgW1SbGD9gHIh@V9qiKp0unkB@9zagGdKgZi3nqwAJUQzRCWR0AOGxRXgc4y8)

Uses Arnauld's Regex expression.

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 117 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:n and(chr(97+int(n[:2]))+f(n[2:])if n[0]in'01'or n[0]=='2'and int(n[1])<6 else chr(97+int(n[0]))+f(n[1:]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYxBDoIwEEX3c4rZtY0s2ioYGzmAKw@ALFBKKOJAao1yeiwaFy7m589k3hun0A60nucm76vbua6QDGFFNb@0nu@2K0eBU2F0KcSqiU2bUrgGqZClIyYVG/xnyXOmWeTwC6hS7DO0/d3in0j@PCp6xDz65cwOND7CKeDxEWJhAp6t6y0qAxj8ZLrcLQ9cANrXxY7BnL2troBfvEvYKbCk4V00SlCgU9AZKL0GuUQcucQmfQM)

Recursive `lambda` function.

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 135 bytes

```python
def f(n):
 if n=='':return''
 d=n[0]
 if d in'01'or d=='2'and int(n[1])<6:a,b=n[:2],n[2:]
 else:a,b=d,n[1:]
 return chr(97+int(a))+f(b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY5BjsIwDEX3OUV2jkUXSRgYEZEDsOIApYuWJmoLMlVwxXD6TgILf9nP/l@e3zw8aLuufYgyKkIn5BgleQ/gUuAlEYCQvadaN59VL0cCbeCRMvVgoaWCWFFtGjzuXVt1@drZpqLaumwK92f40D4TU8g3WF6HpA6/m2JuETdRdbjOqYxwonnhC8vzwrkBFK9hvAdp8nuc3m7yYzlQmNP/rmFm16XQ3oT82qcKLgxVVBPiqoURdifsXhi7FbpILl3kZ/cP)

Recursive `def` function.

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 212 bytes

```python
def f(n,i=0,o='',c=lambda s:chr(97+int(s))):
 while i<len(n)-1:
  d=n[i]
  if d in'01':i+=1;o+=c(d+n[i])
  elif d=='2'and int(n[i+1])<6:i+=1;o+=c(d+n[i])
  else:o+=c(n[i])
  i+=1
 if i<len(n):o+=c(n[i])
 return o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dU5LTsMwEN37FLOzLRvJTmkRpj4AKw5Au0gTR3EITuRMBD198FB1wYLFPI3eZ@bNV@yntNu2NnTQiaSjN3rynOvGj/Xnpa1hcU2fxfOTignFIqV0DL76OAaIxzEkkeSDLRS0Pr3Hc1liBy3ExI3lLipvXyblG9EqkmXRw0gO73nF60ROFEVS9iyPh38CS3C/3J0hF6NH9wp/5BxwzQmmbc50nL@mecUTwtuKZeGS3epTa8xXN/hIBlGS4bsJM7pLDvUHg1t80PyEXHdikHIzzLJqz6oDs9WOGYIyhuBx/wM)

Iterative `def` function.

Comment: Answering your own posting right away is unfair (you've had more time to work on it). Would have been much better to put a link in your OP to one of these as example code.

Comment: As a note, it's better to wait a few days before doing so (usually if your post gets lots of answers), otherwise wait a little longer (max a week)

Comment: In TheThonnu's defence: this doesn't really look like it was meant as a competing entry to me.